# Android: How to record the orientation change in MediaProjection API

Tags: android, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to record the orientation change(Landscape, Upsidedown landscape and upsidedown vertical)  with the screen recorder api of android(mediaprojection api)

As in I want the recorded video's orientation to be changed when the screen's orientation is changed while recording.

I was looking to maybe pass some parameters to a function in `MediaProjection` API but couldn't find a function to do that. 
The `createVirtualDisplay()` method in `MediaProjection` API takes the following parameters:
`VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay (String name, int width, int height, int dpi, int flags, Surface surface, VirtualDisplay.Callback callback, Handler handler)`

But it doesn't take the orientation parameter. Am I missing something?